# Reference imported object based on env

Tags: node.js, typescript

In my TypeScript Node app I wish to reference the exported object that matches my NODE_ENV variable.

**config.ts**

```
const test: { [index: string]: any } = {
    param1: "x",
    param2: {
        name: "John"
    }
}
const dev: { [index: string]: any } = {
    param1: "y",
    param2: {
        name: "Mary"
    }
}
export { test, dev }
```

**main.ts**

```
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
import * as config from "./config.ts";
const envConfig = config[environment]; //gives error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("/path_to_config.ts")'.ts(7053)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the implicit `any` explicit:

`const envConfig: any = (config as any)[environment];`

This error often arises when you try to access a property of an object via `['propertyName']` instead of `.propertyName`, since that form bypasses TypeScript's type checking in many cases.

Comment: Thank you kshetline that did it. If BTW the above could be done in a more elegant way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a bit better than `any` by defining a type which is constrained to all possible values (which you could export from your config.tsx) e.g.

```
type configType ='test' | 'dev'

const envConfig = config[environment as configType];
```

Comment: nice suggestion but still giving me the same error.